# Fetch data from three table in my sql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

1. **tbl_category**

   - c_ID
   - cat_name
2. **tbl_subcategory**

   - c_ID
   - catID *FOREIGN KEY* of ***tbl_category***
   - sub_Name
3. **tbl_treatment**

   - t_ID
   - subID *FOREIGN KEY* of ***tbl_subcategory***
   - treat_Name

Now I want to fetch data like this:

```
treat_Name sub_Name cat_name where subID = 1001
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, normally you'd do something like `JOIN tbl_subcategory ON tbl_subcategory.c_ID = tbl_category.catId`, is that not working for some reason?  Which RDBMS are you actually using?  Although solutions are likely db-agnostic... And prefixing things with `tbl_` is probably a terrible idea...

Comment: Why this question is tagged with [sql-server] and [oracle] if question's title is `Fetch data from three table in **my sql**` ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to `JOIN` the three tables :

```
SELECT c.treat_Name, 
       b.sub_Name,
       a.cat_name
FROM   tbl_category a,
       tbl_subcategory b,
       tbl_treatment c
WHERE  a.c_id = b.catid
AND    b.c_id = c.subid
AND    c.subid = 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

Well use INNER JOIN for this issue

```
SELECT c.treat_Name, 
       b.sub_Name,
       a.cat_name
FROM   ((tbl_category a INNER JOIN tbl_subcategory b 
       ON a.c_ID = b.catID)
       INNER JOIN tbl_treatment c
       ON b.catID = c.subID)
WHERE  c.subID = 1001
```

Comment: @Snehal: Was this any helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

they below:

```
SELECT c.treat_Name, 
       b.sub_Name,
       a.cat_name
       FROM   tbl_treatment c  inner join tbl_subcategory b
       on  b.c_id = c.subid
       inner join 
       tbl_category a
       on a.c_id = b.catid          
       where    c.subid = 1001
```